# Adding gedit to my PATH

Tags: path

I finally made the jump and got a MacBook, and I'm trying to move in. I have the OSX port of gedit installed, but I'm having trouble adding it to my PATH. My current PATH looks like this:

`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/gedit:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

as per a comment [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/jessevdk/2009/06/10/gedit-os-x-for-realz/).

Comment: OK, reading the comment I may have misunderstood the question. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: If you _really_ want to "make the jump", I recommend a real Mac-centric editor, TextMate. It comes with a shell command that'll launch it, "mate", it's free, and it's significantly superior to gedit (and most other editors, IMHO.) You'll ease your transition into loving OSX if you accept doing things differently, starting with dumping your Gnome apps.

Comment: @nix Textmate is not free. It's like $40.

Comment: @loic-wolff Oh, so it is. Well worth it!! I guess i bought it so long ago, i forgot, LOL

Comment: But I agree with @nix. Try to look for a native app. Fraiseapp (http://fraiseapp.com) is really nice and free. And if you really like it, Smultron which has the same core is on the App Store for only a few bucks.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I was trying to run gedit form bash. Also, I'd be using TextMate if it were free. Once I get a few extra bucks, I'd like to pick it up... what are some advantages of TextMate over gedit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add the **path** to the folder containing the gedit binary, not the path to the binary.

Try this

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

Note: On OS X, you don't need `/Application` apps to be in the PATH to launch them.

```
open -a gedit
```

Check [man open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)