# Changing your path variable

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding gedit to my PATH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/adding-gedit-to-my-path)

I'm very new to OSX.

I installed Ruby with HomeBrew, and the rubygems installer said that I should add a certain path (`/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/bin`) to my PATH variable.

Great, I obviously don't know how to do that, so I used the advice on [this](http://keito.me/tutorials/macosx_path) site.  However, I assume I messed it up completely, because I think that is the only thing contained in my PATH variable.  For example, `ls` doesn't work in terminal anymore - I'm guessing that's because it's contained in a folder that used to be included in PATH and now is not.

If I type `echo $PATH` I only get the one directory back (`/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/bin`).

Have I completely stuffed it now?  Can I get it back?  And how the hell do you edit your path variable?